# jquery UI datepicker not working on dynamically inserted input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, dynamically-generated

I am adding input field dynamically to a `td` element

```
$('.edit_text').live('click',function(){
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).text()+'" style="background:url(text_bx.gif) no-repeat bottom;display:inline;padding: 0; margin: 0;" class="editing" >');
    $(this).children('input').focus();
    if ($(this).attr('id')=='date'){
        $(this).children('input').datepicker( "refresh");//"option", "dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
    }
});
```

But if td has id date, datepicker is not showing up.
I also have blur function on inserted input field, is that a problem?

```
$('.editing').live('blur',function(){
//did something
    });
```

Comment: can you post on jsfiddle? also try using some different names rather than "date" which can get you into trouble

Comment: the code is a bit complicated and I added console.log(0) after if statement and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Well, Below is the dynamic `jquery date picker` with editable textbox you can update the code accordingly.

```js
$(function(){
    
    $('#thedate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
         onSelect: function(dateText) {
     $('#dateContainer').text(dateText);
        console.log(dateText);
        }
        
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
Shown Date : <div id="dateContainer" type="button" > currentData </div>
<input id="thedate" type="text" /><br />
<input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

***JS Fiddle with date picker:-***
http://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/8w8v9/1989/

***JS Fiddle with date picker and div:-***
http://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/8w8v9/1990/

***Hoping this will help you :)***