# Jquery datepicker not working well on dynamic input fields

Tags: jquery, datepicker

My jquery datepicker not work well in dynamic input fields, when i click the add button only  first field the datepicker is work, then the 2nd, 3rd, .... its not working. Is there anyone can help my problem? Thanks.

Here is the javascript

```
var MaxInputs = 8;
var InputsWrapperRates = $("#InputsWrapperRates");
var AddButtonRates     = $("#AddMoreFileBoxRates");

var z = InputsWrapperRates.length;
var FieldCountRates = 0;  
$(AddButtonRates).click(function (e) { 
    if(z <= MaxInputs) {
        FieldCountRates++;        
        var block = $('<div class=textWrap><input class="smaller" type="text" name="season[]" id="field_'+ FieldCountRates +'" placeholder="Season '+ FieldCountRates +'"/><input class="smaller" type="text" name="stay[]" id="field_'+ FieldCountRates +'" placeholder="Minimum Stay '+ FieldCountRates +'"/><input class="smaller" type="text" name="date1[]" id="field_'+ FieldCountRates +'" data-field="date" placeholder="From date 1" readonly/><input class="smaller" type="text" name="date2[]" id="field_'+ FieldCountRates +'" data-field="date" placeholder="To date 1" readonly/><input class="smaller" type="text" name="date3[]" id="field_'+ FieldCountRates +'" data-field="date" placeholder="From date 2" readonly/><input class="smaller" type="text" name="date4[]" id="field_'+ FieldCountRates +'" data-field="date" placeholder="To date 2" readonly /><a href="#" class="removeclassRates">&times;</a><div class="dtBox'+z+'"></div></div>')
        $(InputsWrapperRates).append(block);  
        $("#dtBox"+z).DateTimePicker();
        z++; 
    }
    return false;
});
```

here is the html

```
<div id="InputsWrapperRates">
    <button id="AddMoreFileBoxRates">Add Villa Rates</button>
    <div id="dtBox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486660/jquery-ui-datepicker-not-working-on-dynamically-inserted-input?rq=1

Comment: You are using same ID for multiple elements. Use class instead. It will work for classes.

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha LOL, thanks. i forgot to change the selector

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/10/